# Issue accessing $dbconnect within OO PHP mysqli select method

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to create a OO PHP database class, but am having issues working out how to pass my $dbconnect variable into a 'select' method. Here's my code below:

```
class Database {

private $db_host = "host";
private $db_user = "user";
private $db_pass = "password";
private $db_name = "dbname";
private $result = array();
private $myQuery = "";
private $numResults = "";

public function connect() {

    $dbconnect = mysqli_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->db_name);
    if(mysqli_connect_errno()) {

        array_push($this->result, mysqli_connect_error());
        return false;

    } else {

        $this->con = true;
        return true;

    }

}

public function select($table, $rows = '*', $join = null, $where = null, $order = null, $limit = null) {

    $sql = 'SELECT '.$rows;
    if($table) {
        $sql .= ' FROM '.$table;
    }
    if($join != null) {
        $sql .= ' JOIN '.$join;
    }
    if($where != null) {
        $sql .= ' WHERE '.$where;
    }
    if($order != null) {
        $sql .= ' ORDER BY '.$order;
    }
    if($limit != null) {
        $sql .= ' LIMIT '.$limit;
    }

    $query = $dbconnect->query($sql);
    $this->myQuery = $sql;

    if($query->num_rows > 0) {

        $this->numResults = $query->num_rows;

        for($i = 0; $i < $this->numResults; $i++) {

            $r = mysqli_fetch_array($query);
            $key = array_keys($r);
            for($x = 0; $x < count($key); $x++) {

                if(!is_int($key[$x])) {
                    if(mysqli_num_rows($query) >= 1) {
                        $this->result[$i][$key[$x]] = $r[$key[$x]];
                    } else {
                        $this->result = null;
                    }
                }

            }

        }
        return true;

    } else {

        //array_push($this->selectresult, 'No rows returned');
        return false;

    }

}
```

So I have a method to create the database connection, which assigns that to a $dbconnect variable. My issue is that I then need to be able to get this variable within my select method as I'm using mysqli...but can't do so with my above code. I get the following error:

Notice: Undefined variable: dbconnect

Any help pointing out where I'm going wrong would be great.

Comment: 1) This `$this->con = true;` is wrong, I don't see any instance member `$con` in your class. 2) You have been given two answers below, both should work for you.

Answer (score 2):

Declare it as a class property

```
private $dbconnect;
```

Then in your constructor, initialize it

```
$this->dbconnect = mysqli_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->db_name);
```

now you can reference it throughout the rest of your class as `$this->dbconnect`

Answer (score 2):

You can create a property of this class

```
protected $dbconnect;
```

and then create a constructor that sets the value of `$dbconnect`

```
public function __construct()
{
     $this->dbconnect = mysqli_connect($this->db_host, $this->db_user, $this->db_pass, $this->db_name);
}
```

and then in your select() function use

`$query = $this->dbconnect->query($sql);` instead of `$query = $dbconnect->query($sql);`

Hope this helps.